# in google map clustering (ios /objective c), changing the cluster icons method not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am using google map clusering (https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils).

There(https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/app/BasicViewController.m) one of the method to change cluster icons are not working.

```
- (id<GMUClusterIconGenerator>)iconGeneratorWithImages 
{  
return [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc] initWithBuckets:@[ @10, @50, @100, @200, @1000 ]
                                                backgroundImages:@[
                                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"m1.png"],
                                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"m2.png"],
                                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"m3.png"],
                                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"m4.png"],
                                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"m5.png"]
                                                ]];
}
```

new cluster images will not shown in map. why it is not working? I need to change the cluster icons in map. 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you’re trying to make the example code work with custom cluster-marker images.
It seems like that the `iconGeneratorWithImages` method is never called and hence this returned `GMUClusterIconGenerator` object is never assigned as the `GMUDefaultClusterRenderer`’s `clusterIconGenerator`.

To make it work, I think what you’ll have to do is replace `id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [self defaultIconGenerator];` in [Line 60](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/app/BasicViewController.m#L60) with `id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [self iconGeneratorWithImages];`